# How to calculate CheckSum8 2s Complement

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to calculate checksum of bytes array in javascript but not able to do this. Here is the ref website that provides the result

https://www.scadacore.com/tools/programming-calculators/online-checksum-calculator/

let value = ffee031000149267cf4596675897a710d9c1368c1d8dbe27d05513ded16374f6f572666f6aa0

result  = 57

how to achieve this in javascript?

Tried Code

```
const CalculateChecksum = (value) =>{
      let test = value.match(/.{1,2}/g);
      const intValue = BigInt(`0x${value.toString('hex')}`);
       return Number(intValue % BigInt(37));
    }
```

Comment: Please show us what you tried, instead of just telling us that you were _"not able to do this"_. [ask], [mre]

Answer (score 1):

The general strategy is this:

1. split the string into bytes
2. sum up all the bytes
3. only look at the lowest 8 bits
4. since the result should be "the amount you need to add to the sum to get 0," you have to subtract this sum from 256.

And here's some sample code:

```js
const stringToByteArray = (value) => {
    if (value.length % 2 !== 0) {
        return stringToByteArray(`0${value}`);
    }
    return [...value]
        .reduce((result, _, index) => {
            if (index % 2 === 0) {
                return [...result, value.substring(index, index + 2)];
            }
            return result;
        }, [])
        .map((value) => {
            return parseInt(value, 16);
        });
};

const checksum = (bytes) => {
    return (
        256 -
        (bytes.reduce((total, next) => {
            return total + next;
        }, 0) %
            256)
    );
};

const CalculateChecksum = (value) => {
    return checksum(stringToByteArray(value));
};

const v =
    'ffee031000149267cf4596675897a710d9c1368c1d8dbe27d05513ded16374f6f572666f6aa0';
const c = CalculateChecksum(v);
console.log(`0x${c.toString(16)}`);
```

[Reference](http://www.planetimming.com/checksum8.html)

Comment: @Suraj Welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solves your question, you can mark it as accepted using the check mark button.